# Why does my loop continuously loop after sleeping even when the statement evaluates to false

Tags: c++

So when I execute this code, the code continues to loop after I've let go of my left mouse button and I don't know why.

Expected result: I hold down left mouse, program clicks continuously until I release left mouse

Actual results: I hold down left mouse, sometimes the will program click continuously and stop after I release the mouse, other times it will keep going and not stop until I click my left mouse manually 1-5 times.

I'm like 99% sure that the problem is with the `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`. I think the problem is that when `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` is called and I release my left mouse while the thread is sleeping, it continuously loops the code and then stops when it figures out that the mouse button isn't actually held down from me clicking manually.

```
INPUT input[1] = {};
input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input[0].mi.dx = 0;
input[0].mi.dy = 0;
input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

INPUT input2[1];
input2[0] = input[0];
input2[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

std::random_device rand_dev;
std::mt19937 generator(rand_dev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr2(30, 60);

while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0 && (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)))
{                       
    SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(distr2(generator)));
    SendInput(1, input2, sizeof(INPUT));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(distr2(generator)));
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. For example, what is `distr2`? How is `distr2` initialized?

Comment: I also recommend that you read the "Remarks" section of [the `GetAsyncKeyState` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate). Especially the part if another process also calls `GetAsyncKeyState` then that could give you false results in your process.

Comment: Added the distr2, and I don't think that another process is calling GetAsyncKeyState since I closed all of them and then tested,

Comment: You didn't say what's in `input` or `input2` but I'm guessing that they are a mousedown and a mouseup, respectively. You are generating input that is simulating mouse activity, which is conflicting with the mouse activity you are generating by manually clicking.

Comment: Yeah but if I don't call the sleep function, this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: You are generating input that interferes with the physical input. It shouldn't be surprising that things behave erratically.

Comment: Do you think an alternative to the sleep functions which doesn't pause the whole thread would work?